# python / pandas = error in pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas

I must have become blind.
I want to sum some figures from a table. As by my idea, the two following codes must give the same output, but they don't :
I have a simple df :

```
df[["Opportunity Group", "enjeu", "Montant"]].sample(10)
```

which gives me : 
[image]

Now for each customer I want the total amount of the df :

```
tab = df.pivot_table(index    = "Opportunity Group",
                    columns  = "enjeu"            ,
                    values   = "Montant"          ,
                    margins  = False              ,
                    aggfunc  = np.sum             ).fillna(0)
tab
```

Which gives me : 
[image]
but the figures are wrong, and if I do the following :

```
df[df["Opportunity Group"]=="NUTANIX"].groupby("enjeu")["Montant"].sum()
```

I don't get the same figures :

```
enjeu
(-1.0, 100.0]                     0.00
(100.0, 200.0]                    0.00
(200.0, 500.0]                    0.00
(500.0, 1000.0]                   0.00
(1000.0, 5000.0]               4208.64
(5000.0, 20000.0]             34393.65
(20000.0, 50000.0]           422983.67
```

Why is not :

```
tab = df.pivot_table(index    = "Opportunity Group",
                    columns  = "enjeu"            ,
                    values   = "Montant"          ,
                    margins  = False              ,
                   aggfunc  = np.sum             ).fillna(0)
```

equivalent of the specific request by group, like for NUTANIX :

```
df[df["Opportunity Group"]=="NUTANIX"].groupby("enjeu")["Montant"].sum()
```

??

## EDIT

the column "enjeu" get's mixed up by the pivot table
Before : 
[image]
After :
[image]

Comment: Please post data as text instead of pictures to help create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).